# Using UML stereotype in a Rational Software Architect model

Tags: uml, ibm-rational, stereotype

I am trying to set up and use a sterotype in IBM Rational Software Architect (9.1) model. I can create the stereotype in the model but its not showing when I try to apply to the metaclass (class in this case).

A pointer to documentation would be helpful, if not some directions. The RSA documentation seems incomplete and out of date. Anything from Google is years old. The last response to a question in the RSA forum is from 2 years ago.

Comment: Did you first apply the Profile containing your stereotype to your model ?

Comment: Just consider to use another tool than _this_ one ;-)

Comment: @Thomas Kilian Could you provide an argumentation ? Of course applying stereotypes works perfectly with this tool...

Comment: @RomainBernard I worked with the predecessor 20 years ago. Argh, Got in touch with RSA some years ago. Twice the argh. Too bloated, too expensive. If you like it, then fine. I don't. And I won't recommend it either. Ah, if you have the answer to the question, then why don't you just write it down?

Answer (score 0):

ok, an expert user showed me how. You a) edit the model, b) go to the Profiles tab and c) add the profile there. The stereotypes from the profile will be available when you edit the model elements and go to the Stereotypes tab.

I cant find any documentation on this at all, but its simple and logical when you know how.

Thomas, I was with you on your opinions historically. But now am finding version 9.1 good. I tried 9.7 on my personal laptop and its better again, including the documentation. My opinion now is that RSA is better that some of the other tools I have to use. The documentation is not visible on Google, only through the tool Help, which I dont understand.